# type mismatch in string concatenation

Tags: scala, concatenation, type-mismatch, gatling

I'm really new to Scala and I'm not even able to concatenate Strings. Here is my code:

```
object RandomData {

private[this] val bag = new scala.util.Random

def apply(sensorId: String, stamp: Long, size: Int): String = {
  var cpt: Int = 0
  var data: String = "test"
  repeat(10) {
    data += "_test"
  }
  return data
}
}
```

I got the error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: com.excilys.ebi.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: The snippet you show is too short to give an answer. Where and how do you make use of Gatling? In which line does your type error occur?

Comment: the type error occurred at the line data += "_test". This will be an "helper" function for gatling scenarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repeat` is offered by Gatling in order to repeat Gatling tasks, e.g., query a website. If you have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Structure-Elements#wiki-repeat) (I wasn't able to find a link to the API doc of `repeat`), you'll see that repeat expects a *chain*, which is why your error message says "required: com.excilys.ebi.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder". However, all you do is to append to a string - which will not return a value of type `ChainBuilder`.

Moreover, appending to a string is nothing that should be done via Gatling. It looks to me as if you are confusing Gatling's `repeat` with a Scala [`for` loop](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/scala/for.html). If you only want to append `"_test"` to `data` 10 times, use one of Scala's loops (`for`, `while`) or a functional approach with e.g. `foldLeft`. Here are two examples:

```
/* Imperative style loop */
for(i <- 1 to 10) {
  data += "_test"
}

/* Functional style with lazy streams */
data += Stream.continually("_test").take(10).mkString("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the block

```
{
  data += "_test"
}
```

evaluates to `Unit`, whereas the `repeat` method seems to want it to evaluate to a `ChainBuilder`.

Check out the documentation for the `repeat` method. I was unable to find it, but it's probably reasonable to assume that it looks something like

```
def repeat(numTimes: Int)(thunk: => ChainBuilder): Unit
```

I'm not sure if the `repeat` method does anything special, but with your usage, you could just use this block instead of the `repeat(10){...}`

```
for(i <- 1 to 10) data += "_test"
```

Also, as a side note, you don't need the `return` keyword with scala. You can just say `data` instead of `return data`.